# DevExpress.XtraEditors.LookUpEdit not found

Tags: devexpress

When trying to upgrade from v2009 1.2 to v2009 3.3, I get the following error:

"The type 'DevExpress.XtraEditors.LookUpEdit' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'DevExpress.XtraEditors.v9.1, Version=9.1.2.0"

However, I can see the LookUpEdit in the version 3.3. Am I missing something? Please help.

Comment: It sounds as if you have two versions of the DevExpress.XtraEditors assembly referenced in your project. Did you run the Project Converter tool after you upgraded to v2009 3.3? Do you see duplicate references?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I did not change the assemblies in the dependent projects.